# How do I call a method from an rspec test

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

I'm learning Ruby and TDD (rspec) at the same time.

I've written the following test:

```
describe is_eligible do
  it "returns true if the passed in string is not part of a list" do
    result = is_eligible("abc")
    result.should eq(false)
  end
end
```

It is testing the following code:

```
def is_eligible(team_name)
  array = Array.new
  array << "abc" << "def" << "ghi"
  if array.include?(team_name)
    return false
  else
    return true
  end
end
```

I'm receiving the following error and can't find out why.

*/Users/joel.dehlin/top32/lib/ineligible_teams.rb:6:in `is_eligible': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)*

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: BTW, for testing truthy/false values, it's best to use `.should be_true` or `should be_false`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `describe` method expects a string or something that can evaluate to string. If you say "is_eligible" without the quotes, it will actually try to call the method and you get the error.

```
describe "is_eligible" do
  it "returns true if the passed in string is not part of a list" do
    result = is_eligible("abc")
    result.should eq(false)
  end
end
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you! Why do you pass in a string of the method name instead of just the method name?

Comment: Because in ruby, the parentheses after a method call are optional (in most cases) - so when you say "describe is_eligible", it's actually the same thing as "describe is_eligible()". And because describe is just a method that takes an argument and a block, it's basically "describe(is_eligible()) {...}". By the way, if the answer solves your problem, please accept it.